# Flex + Access XML Content

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I have a structure like

This is what

```
data.data = <node classid="1" label="Teacher" Addr="#1, CP"/>
```

How can I access the content, i tried

1. data.data.@node.label
2. data.data.node.label
3. data.data.label

Any help!!

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Comment: Sorry James, forgot to put it in the code tag :)

Comment: Also when I print data.data it shows "", but while debugging when I watch the parameter, it had an XML structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> data.data.@classid
>
> data.data.@label

You need to use @ to get XML data values.

Read [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/accessing_xml_data/) article for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments, there was an issue with the data I was assigning to the data provider, got it resolved.